# Asymmetric encryption between android and php

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

The following asymmetric functions are used to encrypt and decrypt in android.. it work perfectly. However, when I encrypt using the function below and decrypt using php or another function(which is quite similar using eclipse).. I get null .. bad padding exception .. I cannot figure out the issue .. as i am encoding the result .. and why does it work only if I encrypt and decrypt in android or in eclipse .. but doesn't work between php and android or simply between two java programs .. but on eclipse and android..

Android Program:

```
public  String encryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    byte[] crypted = null;
    try{

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }//Base64.encodeBase64(crypted)

    return new String(Base64.encode(crypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
}
public  String decryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key){
    byte[] output = null;
    try{

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);//Base64.decodeBase64(input.getBytes())
        output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return new String(output);
}
```

Eclipse (Java program as well):

```
public static String encryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key){
      byte[] crypted = null;

      try{

          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
          crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }//Base64.encodeBase64(crypted)
        return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(crypted));
    }
public static String decryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key){
    byte[] output = null;
    try{

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);//Base64.decodeBase64(input.getBytes())
      output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(input.getBytes()));
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return new String(output);
}
```

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` relies on default mode and padding and is *not* portable. Never do that. `input.getBytes()` relies on default charset and is *not* portable. Never do that.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by portable in this context

Comment: The same code will produce different results on platforms with different platform-default charsets, and will produce different results on Oracle Java platforms versus Android platforms.

Comment: oh that explains my issue .. but how can I substitute "RSA" .. the getBytes function I will search for an alternative

Comment: if I use input.getBytes("UTF-8"); .. will this help?

Comment: Yes, that would work perfectly everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @James in the comments input.getBytes and getInstance are not portable.. I changed by code by adding UTf-8 and wrote RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding instead of RSA and it fixed my problem..

```
 public  String encryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    byte[] crypted = null;
    try{
        byte[] bytes = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
        //String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        crypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }//Base64.encodeBase64(crypted)

    return new String(Base64.encode(crypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
}
public  String decryptAsymmetric(String input, Key key){
    byte[] output = null;
    try{

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);//Base64.decodeBase64(input.getBytes())
        output = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(input.getBytes("UTf-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return new String(output);
}
```